# B4A - webview using chrome browser

Tags: basic4android

In the WebView that is based on default browser of android my website isn't loading correctly, How can I load it using chrome at least in the case that chrome is installed?
Note that I don't want execute chrome browser I want to embed it inside of the application layout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is not possible. The default browser used within the webview is defined within the Android OS so your only option if you wanted to use Chrome is via an intent which would open it externally